# How do I cover a method being called with MethodInvoker under aspect?

Tags: java, aop, spring-aop, aspect

method to be covered for metrics generation:

```
@Override
    @Metric(metricName = "rmq.onMessage", type = { MetricType.METER, MetricType.HISTOGRAM })
    public void onMessage(Object messageBytes) {
    //some processing
    }
```

Registering Method here:

```
 MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapter = new MessageListenerAdapter(messageConsumer, "onMessage");
```

if any messages come in the queue then onMessage will be invoked using:

```
protected Object invokeListenerMethod(String methodName, Object[] arguments, Message originalMessage)
            throws Exception {
        try {
            MethodInvoker methodInvoker = new MethodInvoker();
            methodInvoker.setTargetObject(getDelegate());
            methodInvoker.setTargetMethod(methodName);
            methodInvoker.setArguments(arguments);
            methodInvoker.prepare();
            return methodInvoker.invoke();
        }
```

My Aspect:

```
@Around("@annotation(myAnnotation.graphite.annotations.Metric)")
    public Object graphiteAspect(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) {
      //metrics reporting done here
    }
```